# Huawei Mate SE no update option

Tags: updates, huawei

I got a Huawei Mate SE and have been using it for a few weeks. I've noticed on the internet that it should have the Oreo (8.0) Android update, but I don't see the update option on my phone. Usually, it should be the bottom option in the settings or an app icon on my launcher but it's not there.

My phone was rooted and I had the bootloader unlocked, but I un-rooted it and relocked the bootloader and still can't update. The themes app is back, which goes away when it's unlocked, but I would like to get the latest EMUI version on my phone. Any ideas to get this functionality back? I have also tried factory reset after I relocked it and un-rooted it but no luck.

Comment: Updates are pushed out in batches with respect to regions and device variants. If you are so eager, use TeamMT's Firmware Finder to manually install an update.

Comment: I knew that, but it can't get the update without the update system. The option is actually missing on the device. It should be at the bottom of the settings screen, but it isn't.